# Append string to specific values in a list of dictionary - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is my list of dictionary

```
pool = [{'node_name': '198', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '199','port':'22'}, 
{'node_name': '200', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '201', 'port': '22'}, 
{'node_name': '202', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '203', 'port': '22'}, 
{'node_name': '204', 'port':'22'}, {'node_name': '205', 'port': '22'}]
```

I want to append `node-` as a prefix to the `value` for the `key` `node_name`. I want the output to be like the below

```
[{'node_name': 'node-198', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node- 
199','port':'22'}, 
{'node_name': 'node-200', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-201', 'port': 
'22'}, {'node_name': 'node-202', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-203', 
'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-204', 'port':'22'}, {'node_name': 'node- 
 205', 'port': '22'}]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a preference about whether the dictionaries should be modified?

Comment: Nope! no preference like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers all create *n* new dictionaries and a new list to hold them.

It seems like a waste to do all this just to fit it in one line.

```
for d in x:
    if 'node_name' in d:
        d['node_name'] = 'node-'+d['node_name']
```

Will just modify one dictionary entry and not create any new objects (outside of replacing the strings).

If you knew the key to be in each dictionary,

```
for d in x: d['node_name'] = 'node-'+d['node_name']
```

*boom* - one line...

Comment: That's a nice one-liner. Thank you! Very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary unpacking:

```
pool = [{'node_name': '198', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '199','port':'22'}, {'node_name': '200', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '201', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '202', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '203', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': '204', 'port':'22'}, {'node_name': '205', 'port': '22'}] 
new_pool = [{**i, 'node_name':f'node-{i["node_name"]}'} for i in pool]
```

Output:

```
[{'node_name': 'node-198', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-199', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-200', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-201', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-202', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-203', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-204', 'port': '22'}, {'node_name': 'node-205', 'port': '22'}]
```

Comment: Can the downvoter explain how this post can be improved?

Comment: Cause they don't know xD I hope stackoverflow makes it mandatory to add an explanation to a downvote. I just hate people like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here using `map` and `dictionary unpacking`, also works in python 3.5:

```
>>> new_pool = list(map(lambda x: {**x,'node_name':'node-{}'.format(x['node_name'])},pool))

>>> print(*new_pool,sep='\n')
{'node_name': 'node-198', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-199', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-200', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-201', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-202', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-203', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-204', 'port': '22'}
{'node_name': 'node-205', 'port': '22'}
```